# ActionScript 3.0: Wait for response from Flash Player Settings window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I recently received some code from another developer and there's one piece I would like to rework. It's a **flash app** that works with **mic and webcam**. When it is started you are prompted to press a **button** - after that the usual **flash player settings windows** appears asking you to allow access to mic and cam. The application needs to **wait** for user's response on this question. It was achieved in the code I received in a rather awkward fashion. Application progressed on **mouse movement** event, which would not be registered since the flash player settings popup block the area. Once it out of the way - any mouse move would make application to go on. I need to rework with in some better way, because this piece of code is **also** used in AIR application that doesn't ask for allowance and, therefore, if you click the opening button you would need to move your mouse in order to get things running. I believe there must be some decent way to notify the app that settings popup is gone. Could anyone advice on this?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any API to do this, and you have to use hacks like yours above. The one you are using is the cleaner solutions I've seen. Maybe you should just detect if your app is running in AIR or in a browser, and only use the mouse move technique when running in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this in Flash Player is to listen for `StatusEvent.STATUS` event which is dispatched after the user either allows or denies you access to their mic. See [the documentation for Microphone.getMicrophone()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#getMicrophone%28%29).

In AIR, however, you don't have to ask for user's permission to access their mic and camera, so this event is not dispatched when your application gets access to the input device. In that case, you can check through [Capabilities.playerType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType) property if your code is running in AIR and then proceed with doing what you would have done in response to receiving permission to access user's input devices.